# Warning CS0675: The operator `|' used on the sign-extended type `int'

Tags: c#, unity3d, типы-данных

Есть код на C#, который используется в Unity3D. Visual Studio в нем предупреждений не находит, однако компилятор в юнити выводит предупреждение:

`warning CS0675: The operator`|' used on the sign-extended type `int'. Consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first`

Кусок кода, на который ругается:

```
long old = _outKey[8] & 0xff;
old |= _outKey[9] << 0x08 & 0xff00;
old |= _outKey[10] << 0x10 & 0xff0000;
old |= _outKey[11] << 0x18 & 0xff000000;
```

Проблема в приведении типов. Изначально этот код портирован из Java, где всё нормально, и переменная вообще была типа int. Однако, шарпу не нравятся такие вот битовые операции над знаковыми числами.

А если переменную объявлять как int - то на последней строке VS ругается на необходимость привести long к int (почему??? там же 4 байта?!).

Так же пытался объявлять uint - так же требует приводить типы.

Подскажите, какой тип данных лучше использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл Ваш предыдущий топик, предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```
byte[] _inKey = new byte[16];
uint old = (uint)_inKey[8] & (uint)0xff;
old |= (uint)_inKey[9] << 8 & (uint)0xff00;
old |= (uint)_inKey[10] << 0x10 & (uint)0xff0000;
old |= (uint)_inKey[11] << 0x18 & (uint)0xff000000;
```

Long в .NET всегда 8-ми байтовый в отличие от плюсов)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь начал понимать типизацию.

Answer (score 5):

Компилятор вам указывает на то, что ваш код потенциально является источником довольно серьезной и трудноуловимой ошибки. Вы пытаетесь применить оператор "ИЛИ" к операнду, допускающему отрицательные значения, а результат сохранять в переменной большего размера. 
Скажем, если вы станете выполнять побитовые операции с отрицательным операндом типа int, а потом сохраните все это в long, то рискуете получить что-то невменяемое из-за особенностей преставления отрицательных чисел в памяти компьютера (гуглить по словосочетанию "Дополнительный код"). 
Вместо int вам имеет смысл использовать что-нибудь беззнаковое, скажем, uint